# Discriminator with many-to-many relationship EF Core 6

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

i'm trying to put in place a relation with a distriminator (i think) in EfCore 6

I have `Users`, `Posts` and `Groups` linked to multiple `Tag` through a many-to-many relationship defined with an entity `Tagging`.
We are on PostGreSQL.

I can't figure out how to make this relation work

```
public class User {
  public long Id {get; set;}
  // other properties

  public ICollection<Tag> Tags {get; set;}
}
```

```
public class Group{
  public long Id {get; set;}
  // other properties
}
```

```
public class Post {
  public long Id {get; set;}
  // other properties
}
```

```
public class Tag {
  public long Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

```
public class Tagging {
  public long Id {get; set;}
  public long TagId {get; set;}
  public long TaggableId {get; set;}
  public string TaggableType {get; set;}
}
```

```
builder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Tags)
    .WithMany(t => t.Users)
    .UsingEntity<Tagging>(
      j => j
        .HasOne(ta => ta.Tag)
        .WithMany(t => t.Taggings)
        .HasForeignKey(ta => ta.TagId),
      j => j
        .HasOne(ta => ta.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.Taggings)
        .HasForeignKey(ta => ta.TaggableId),
      j =>
      {
        j.HasKey(ta => ta.Id);
      }
    );
```

If the `TaggableType` property of `Taggings`

1. is `User` then the `TaggableId` must point to `User`
2. is `Post` then the `TaggableId` must point to `Post`
3. is `Group` then the `TaggableId` must point to `Group`

I read about TPT and TPH but i'm a bit lost.

i tried with `hasQueryFilter` but because it's a general query filer, it applies to `Post` and `Group`.

Edit 17/10
So i created a `TaggingGroup` class

```cs
public class TaggingGroup : Tagging
{
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

added it to the db context and specified the base type.

```cs
public virtual DbSet<TaggingGroup> TaggingGroups { get; set; } = null!;

modelBuilder.Entity<TaggingGroup>(entt =>
{
  entt.HasBaseType<Tagging>();
});
```

Specified the discriminator

```cs
entity.HasDiscriminator(ta => ta.TaggableType)
    .HasValue<TaggingGroup>(TagTaggableTypes.Group)
    .HasValue<TaggingUser>(TagTaggableTypes.User)
    .HasValue<TaggingPost>(TagTaggableTypes.Post);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use inheritance, as TPH is default for EF 6. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) for details. But the main idea is a (maybe even abstract) class `Tagging` with 3 separate classes that inherit from it.

Edit 18/10

After further investigation I found 2 possible ways:

1. Dropping the whole automatic many to many concept and focus on `Tagging` TPH inheritance:

```
    public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Tagging> Taggings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Group
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TaggingGroup> Taggings { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TaggingUser> Taggings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TaggingPost> Taggings { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Tagging
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaggingUser : Tagging
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaggingGroup : Tagging
    {
        public Group Group { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaggingPost : Tagging
    {
        public Post Post { get; set; }
    }
```

for the classes and for the context just this:

```
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tagging> Taggings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TaggingGroup> TaggingGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TaggingPost> TaggingPosts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TaggingUser> TaggingUsers { get; set; }
```

For my local sample I did not use any extra code for the `OnModelCreating` method of the context.

The generated DB Tables were what I was expecting for this scenario.

You could maybe use a property `Tags` in the `User`,`Post` and `Group` classes like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags
    {
        get
        {
            return Taggings.Select(p => p.Tag);
        }
    }
```

But investigate performance regarding to lazy loading and DB roundtrips and adjust configuration accordingly.

2. Use a less "pretty" way (at least IMHO) and get an automatic many to many mapping (which is basically TPT):

```
    public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Group
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

with a basic DbContext (again no need for explicit `OnModelCreating` in this case):

```
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

*Final note: I was using SQL Server for generating SQL, but I suspect this should not play a significant role in the end*

Comment: I tried, did a `TaggingGroup` class, inheritance and adding the discriminator on the tagging_type property and adding a group property to handle the relation. But now the tag class saying that the tagging class does not content a Group property for the relation and the key saying that the props must be on the class itself and not the parent

Comment: @MrDeliK could you please update the question with those changes?

Comment: the edit is done :)

Comment: After that, i just don't understand how to map the relation.

Comment: @MrDeliK answer updated